# Compilation error : left ambiguous, right ambiguous

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm getting a compilation error saying 'left' and 'right' are ambiguous.

Did I declare left, right at wrong place?

- Declaring inside main doesn't help either
- Moving function definition above main doesn't help

How would I fix this?

Minimum test case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int left = 0, right = 0;
int main()
{
    cout << left;
    cout << right;
}
```

is giving:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6:13: error: reference to ‘left’ is ambiguous
prog.cpp:3:5: error: candidates are: int left
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:918:3: error:
             std::ios_base& std::left(std::ios_base&)
prog.cpp:7:13: error: reference to ‘right’ is ambiguous
prog.cpp:3:15: error: candidates are: int right
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:926:3: error:
             std::ios_base& std::right(std::ios_base&)
```

Comment: Advice for the future - construct [a minimum test case](https://ideone.com/c2DqtQ) and paste the code to into the question, rather than just a link to it.

Comment: i just can't understand code formatting on this site!

Comment: Now you know why you don't do `using namespace std;`!

Comment: The code formatting on this site is Markdown. It's not especially complex. Click the edit link above and see what @Dukeling did, you'll see it's nothing to be afraid of.

Comment: Formatting is quite simple.  Prepare your text with no tabs in it.  Copy into the edit box.  Select each part that should look like code (each block — source code, error messages, etc) and then click on the 'code' button above the edit box — that's the **`{}`** button.  This indents the code by four spaces.  Use blank lines to separate paragraphs.  Enclose words that should appear as code in running text in back-ticks ``'`'``.  Oh, and use the help button to get help on how to use MarkDown.

Comment: @user1776433, well done on fixing your question and responding gracefully to the advise of your peers. Upvoted for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe the error message:

```
raw.cpp:105: error: reference to ‘right’ is ambiguous
raw.cpp:5: error: candidates are: int right
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:917: error:
   std::ios_base& std::right(std::ios_base&)
```

It's intimidating to read, but basically this is what it says:

```
raw.cpp:105: error: There's more than one ‘right’ here
One of them is yours: raw.cpp:5  int right
Another one isn't: <bits/ios_base.h:917>: some crap in namespace ‘std’
```

So `left` and `right` are already defined in `namespace std`, which you are importing all of with `using namespace std`. That's why you have an ambiguity. The simplest change to fix it is remove `using namespace std;` and add `using std::cin; using std::cout;` but this looks like too many global variables for my taste.

By the way, you should incorporate your code into your question. The question might be here longer than that paste, and my answer won't make sense if nobody can see the whole question.

Comment: I didn't know left and right were defined in namespace std, i changed these to lft and rght. Thanks so much.

Comment: If you were in my class I'd drop you a letter grade just for those new variable names. How about `left_index` or `deque_left`?

Comment: Or don't use `using namespace std;` but prefix the items you want from it with `std::`, or specify exactly what you're importing from `std`.  (I think `::left` and `::right` would work too; I'm not sure I'd recommend the notation, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that definitely would be best, especially with some more restrictive scoping or encapsulation.

Comment: @Daniel dequeue_left sounds better. i do not like shorthand myself. Thanks!

Comment: @user1776433 as Daniel suggested, here i would suggest removing `using namespace std;` rather than changing left and right. there is more clarity in 'std::cout' than `cout`,for example.

Comment: `dequeue_left` should be `deque_left`. "To dequeue" is a verb, this is a noun, a deque. Also, in your original code, your error says "undeflow" and should say "underflow."

Comment: Made the suggested changes. Thanks again @Daniel